# How to get ROC curves in a multi-label scenario

Tags: machine-learning

I have a data set with multi-labels. I am trying to generate the ROC curves. Unfortunately, I can not use the code which I frequently used while doing binary classification. How should I modify the code in order to be able to get the ROC curves in a multi-label scenario ? In the error message it says,

> multiclass format is not supported

The code that I use is:

```
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
plt.figure()

models = [
{
'label': 'Logistic Regression',
#'model': LogisticRegression(),
'y_pred': predict_proba[:,1]
},
{
 'label': 'SVM',
 #'model': SVM(),
'y_pred': preds
 },
 {
 'label': 'RandomForestClassifier',
 #'model':  RandomForestClassifier(),
 'y_pred': Y_Pred_proba[:,1]
 },
 ]


for m in models:
   print('LABEL:', m['label'])
   y_pred = m['y_pred']

   fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)

  # fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred, pos_label= 'ovr')
   auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
  # Now, plot the computed values
   plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='%s ROC (area = %0.2f)' % (m['label'], auc))
  # Custom settings for the plot 
  plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
  plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
  plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
  plt.xlabel('1-Specificity(False Positive Rate)')
  plt.ylabel('Sensitivity(True Positive Rate)')
  plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
  plt.legend(loc="lower right")
  plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROC` is a way to evaulate how well a classifier can separate **one** class-distribution from **another** in a given dataset. For a multiclass setting this is per definition not possible. What you can do is, either treat this as a "One vs Rest"-scenario, where you evaluate the performance of your classifier in separating one class from all the others combined, repeating this for every class or you treat this as a "One vs One"-scenario where you compare every possible combination of two classes.
You can find an example with illustrations here (not mine):
[ROC Curve - Multiclass.ipynb](https://github.com/vinyluis/Articles/blob/main/ROC%20Curve%20and%20ROC%20AUC/ROC%20Curve%20-%20Multiclass.ipynb)